# VB webbrowser click on html submit form without id

Tags: vba

I want to do login to the site http://seafight.com.

This is code of login on the site

```html
            </div>
            <fieldset class="bgcdw_login_form_login"><div class="bgcdw_input_text bgcdw_login_form_username">
                    <label for="bgcdw_login_form_username">Nazwa</label>
                    <input id="bgcdw_login_form_username" name="username" type="text" maxlength="20"></div>
                <div class="bgcdw_input_password bgcdw_login_form_password">
                    <label for="bgcdw_login_form_password">Has&#322;o</label>
                    <input id="bgcdw_login_form_password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="45"></div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="bgcdw_login_form_buttons"><input class="bgcdw_button bgcdw_login_form_login" type="submit" value="Logowanie">
    </div>
```

And this is a piece of code in my app

```
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://seafight.com")
    WriteLog("Loading Seafight page...")
    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").InnerText = LoginBox.Text
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = PasswordBox.Text
```

and I don't know how to click submit button because it doesn't have ID. Any ideas?

I tried

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submitButton").InvokeMember("click")
```

and

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button, submit etc")
```

(0 counts with this tag names)